# Stripe doesn't add card to customer - Angular 2 / Express

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I have a problem with adding a card to a customer. I made a simple express server that handles the post request to stripe. At the moment it's register a new customer, but it fails in adding credit card information to the new customer.

In my angular 2 application I collect the credit card information and send it to my Express Server.

**Express server**

```
router.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    console.log('post incomming');
    console.log('reg:', req.body)
    var token = req.body.id;

    stripe.customers.create({
      token: token
    }).then(function(customer) {
      console.log('customer:', customer)
      return stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 1000, // Amount in cents
        currency: "eur",
        customer: customer.id
      });
    }).then(function(err, charge) {
       if(err) {
         console.log('shomething wrong', err);
       }
       if(charge) {
         console.log('charge done');
       };
    });
});
```

Getting the following response from express server

```
Something is happening.                                                                                                                                            
post incomming                                                                                                                                                     
reg: { '{\n  "id": "tok_19ASCZAgR5ZaHhRaLhfk7vcB",\n  "object": "token",\n  "card": {\n    "id": "card_19ASCYAgR5ZaHhRaQZbBj5uj",\n    "object": "card",\n    "addr
ess_city": null,\n    "address_country": null,\n    "address_line1": null,\n    "address_line1_check": null,\n    "address_line2": null,\n    "address_state": null
,\n    "address_zip": null,\n    "address_zip_check": null,\n    "brand": "Visa",\n    "country": "US",\n    "cvc_check": "unchecked",\n    "dynamic_last4": null,\
n    "exp_month": 12,\n    "exp_year": 2017,\n    "funding": "credit",\n    "last4": "4242",\n    "metadata": {},\n    "name": null,\n    "tokenization_method": nu
ll\n  },\n  "client_ip": "90.210.15.78",\n  "created": 1477868095,\n  "livemode": false,\n  "type": "card",\n  "used": false\n}': '' }

customer: { id: 'cus_9TP0BdARBgZ0NF',                                                                                                                              
  object: 'customer',                                                                                                                                              
  account_balance: 0,                                                                                                                                              
  created: 1477868096,                                                                                                                                             
  currency: null,                                                                                                                                                  
  default_source: null,                                                                                                                                            
  delinquent: false,                                                                                                                                               
  description: null,                                                                                                                                               
  discount: null,                                                                                                                                                  
  email: null,                                                                                                                                                     
  livemode: false,                                                                                                                                                 
  metadata: {},                                                                                                                                                    
  shipping: null,                                                                                                                                                  
  sources: { object: 'list',                                                                                                                                               
     data: [],                                                                                                                                                     
     has_more: false,                                                                                                                                              
     total_count: 0,                                                                                                                                               
     url: '/v1/customers/cus_9TP0BdARBgZ0NF/sources' },                                                                                                            
  subscriptions:                                                                                                                                                   
   { object: 'list',                                                                                                                                               
     data: [],                                                                                                                                                     
     has_more: false,                                                                                                                                              
     total_count: 0,                                                                                                                                               
     url: '/v1/customers/cus_9TP0BdARBgZ0NF/subscriptions' } }   

Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card
```

And my Angular 2 applications has to following component and service.

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { CheckoutService } from './checkout.service';
declare var Stripe:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stripe',
  templateUrl: './stripe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stripe.component.css'],
})
export class StripeComponent implements OnInit {
  private cardToken:any;

  constructor(private checkoutService:CheckoutService, private _zone: NgZone) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  setUpCard() {
    //here we setup the stripe publish key.
    //notice that this is a test key for my account so replace with production key(live)
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('PUBKEYHERE');
  }

  getCardData(number, month, year, cvc) {
    //I get the card data typed in here and pass it to the getCardToken method
    this.getCardToken(number, month, year, cvc);
  }

  getCardToken(number, month, year, cvc) {
    //set up the card data as an object
    var dataObj = {"number": number, "exp_month": month, "exp_year": year, "cvc": cvc};

    // Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken(dataObj,
      (status, response) => { //I'm using an arrow function instead of stripeResponseHandler(a function also) cos it's kickass!
        // basically you can do anything here with the reponse that has your token
        // you can hit your backend api and initialize a charge etc
        this._zone.run(() => {
          if (status === 200) {
            this.cardToken = response;
            console.log("the card token: ", this.cardToken);
            this.checkoutService.postToken(this.cardToken);
          }
          else {
            console.log("error in getting card data: ", response.error)
          }
        });
      }
    );

  }
}
```

Checkout service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; 

@Injectable()
export class CheckoutService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  postToken(token) {
    console.log('from the posttoken: ', token);

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/charge', token, {
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe(
      data => console.log('data: ', data),
      err => this.logError(err),
      () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
    );
  }

  logError(err) {
    console.error('There was an error: ' + err);
  }

}
```

When submitting the form I get the following response back:

```
from the posttoken:  Object {id: "tok_19ASCZAgR5ZaHhRaLhfk7vcB", object: "token", card: Object, client_ip: "90.210.15.78", created: 1477868095…}
```

**Question**

Why is Stripe not adding the provided credit card information to the newly created customer?

Comment: Source to charge if you pass a customer id https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge-source or is that optional?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not create card for customer before create charge.

```
router.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    console.log('post incomming');
    console.log('reg:', req.body)
    var token = req.body.id;

    stripe.customers.create({
        token: token,
    }).then(function(customer) {
        console.log('customer:', customer)
        stripe.customers.createSource({
            customer.id,
            {source: token},
        }).then(function(card) {
            return stripe.charges.create({
                amount: 1000, // Amount in cents
                currency: "eur",
                customer: customer.id,
                source: card.id,
            });
        }
    }).then(function(err, charge) {
       if(err) {
         console.log('shomething wrong', err);
       }
       if(charge) {
         console.log('charge done');
       };
    });
});
```